# Flex - saving Serialized ArrayCollection of Objects to File

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, serialization, deserialization, amf

**Creating class with RemoteClass metateg**

```
[RemoteClass]
public class Result 
{
    public function Result(){} 
}
```

**Function for writing in file**

```
public function writeData(object:Object):void
{
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("data.txt");
    if (file.exists)
        file.deleteFile();      
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeObject(object);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

**Function for reading from file**

```
public function readData():Object
{
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("data.txt");
    if(!file.exists) 
        return 0;
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var obj:Object = fileStream.readObject();
    fileStream.close();
    return obj;
}
```

**Function when application initializing**

```
public function initApplication():void
{
    writeData(new Result()); // write object to file.
    var result:Result = readData() as Result; // create Result class object and initializing it data from file
    var array:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); // create collection and fill it objects of Result class
    array.addItem(new Result());
    array.addItem(new Result());
    array.addItem(new Result());
    writeData(array); // writing collection in file
    var arr:ArrayCollection = readData() as ArrayCollection; // initializing new collecion of collection from file.
}
```

**Here is the problem.** Returned collection with objects of Object type.
How can I get collection of Result type objects?
Bad way below

```
for each (var object:Object in arr) 
{
        object = object as Result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [registerClassAlias()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()) before serialization/deserialization

Comment: I can get only one instance of Result class, but can't get the array colection of the Result objects.

Comment: Try to register ArrayCollection as well. There are only few types that you might not need to register, as far as I remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot! RegisterClassAlias() or [RemoteObject] metateg works!